# Launching web app from native app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Does anyone know how to launch a web app from a native app?

I assume that this is hard to achive, but the next best thing would be to launch safari with a specific URL, without the URL-bar. And I don't want it to be done within the app, I would prefer if the native app could go into a suspended state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/"]];
```

and enable multitasking in your app so  when the safari opens your app will go in suspended mode.

**Update -**

Read my these blog entries -

http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/open-phone-sms-email-map-and-browser-apps-in-iphone-sdk/
http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme/

unfortunately you can not open all the apps! but you can add custom URL scheme in your own app to open them

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to invoke a webb app that is installed at the homescreen in some way?

Comment: answer updated please check and if you think this is useful to you then please upvote and accept this answer.. read the SO faq

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to achieve, it's easy with `UIWebView`  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: But does the app that launched the webview go into a suspended state? It seems like the webview is loaded in the app?